# Make column values appear only once in a self join

Tags: python, postgresql

This is a question relating to a Back End Developer course with Udacity.

I am trying to create a system to pair chess players based on their wins. 
I currently have 8 players each with the same number of wins, see:

`player_id |       name        | wins | matches
-----------+-------------------+------+---------
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |    0 |       0
       249 | Fluttershy        |    0 |       0
       250 | Applejack         |    0 |       0
       251 | Pinkie Pie        |    0 |       0
       252 | Rarity            |    0 |       0
       253 | Rainbow Dash      |    0 |       0
       254 | Princess Celestia |    0 |       0
       255 | Princess Luna     |    0 |       0
(8 rows)`

This should result in 4 pairings and should look like this:

`player_id |       name        | player_id |       name
    -----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------
           248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       249 | Fluttershy
           250 | Applejack         |       251 | Pinkie Pie
           252 | Rarity            |       253 | Rainbow Dash
           254 | Princess Celestia |       255 | Princess Luna`

However my output is as follows:

```
player_id |       name        | player_id |       name
-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       249 | Fluttershy
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       250 | Applejack
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       251 | Pinkie Pie
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       252 | Rarity
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       253 | Rainbow Dash
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       254 | Princess Celestia
       248 | Twilight Sparkle  |       255 | Princess Luna
       249 | Fluttershy        |       250 | Applejack
       249 | Fluttershy        |       251 | Pinkie Pie
       249 | Fluttershy        |       252 | Rarity
       249 | Fluttershy        |       253 | Rainbow Dash
       249 | Fluttershy        |       254 | Princess Celestia
       249 | Fluttershy        |       255 | Princess Luna
       250 | Applejack         |       251 | Pinkie Pie
       250 | Applejack         |       252 | Rarity
       250 | Applejack         |       253 | Rainbow Dash
       250 | Applejack         |       254 | Princess Celestia
       250 | Applejack         |       255 | Princess Luna
       251 | Pinkie Pie        |       252 | Rarity
       251 | Pinkie Pie        |       253 | Rainbow Dash
       251 | Pinkie Pie        |       254 | Princess Celestia
       251 | Pinkie Pie        |       255 | Princess Luna
       252 | Rarity            |       253 | Rainbow Dash
       252 | Rarity            |       254 | Princess Celestia
       252 | Rarity            |       255 | Princess Luna
       253 | Rainbow Dash      |       254 | Princess Celestia
       253 | Rainbow Dash      |       255 | Princess Luna
       254 | Princess Celestia |       255 | Princess Luna
(28 rows)
```

As you can see, this is outputting 28 pairings. I need to restrict the code to allow each name to appear only once whether that is in the first set of player_id/name columns or the second set.

I thought that making player_id in the 'standings' table would have prevented duplicates in the join, but this didn't work. 
I also tried to use the 'not in' command and couldn't get this to work. 
I have searched google and specifically stackoverflow to try and find an answer, however most of the similar questions seem to be wanting each possible combination (as above), rather than restricting it to only one appearance of each name.

I am working in python and postgresql. My code is as follows:

```
select a.player_id, a.name, b.player_id, b.name from standings as a, 
standings as b
where a.wins = b.wins
and a.player_id < b.player_id
order by a.wins);
```

The standing table definition is as follows:

`Table "public.standings"
  Column   |  Type   |                           Modifiers
-----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 player_id | integer | not null default nextval('standings_player_id_seq'::regclass)
 name      | text    |
 wins      | integer | default 0
 matches   | integer | default 0
Indexes:
    "standings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (player_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "standings_player_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(player_id)`

Comment: please provide definiton of a atable and some sample data

Comment: Can you post an example of your desired output pls?

Comment: I've added that information to the original question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can try this (at moment it works correctly only for even numbers of names):
Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (248, 'Twilight');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (249, 'Flutter');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (250, 'Apple');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (251, 'Pinkie');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (252, 'Rarity');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (253, 'Rainbow');
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (254, 'Princess C',1);
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (255, 'Princess L',1);
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (278, 'Martins',1);
INSERT INTO TS VALUES (290, 'Karl L',1);
```

Query (it generates single couple for each wins value):

```
WITH TTS AS (SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WINS ORDER BY PLAYER_ID) AS RN
FROM TS)
SELECT A.WINS, A.PLAYER_ID
, A.NAME
, B.PLAYER_ID, B.NAME 
FROM TTS A
INNER JOIN TTS B ON  A.WINS = B.WINS AND A.RN+1=B.RN
WHERE A.RN %2<>0
ORDER BY A.WINS;
```

Output:

```
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| wins | player_id |    name    | player_id |    name    |
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    0 |       248 | Twilight   |       249 | Flutter    |
|    0 |       250 | Apple      |       251 | Pinkie     |
|    0 |       252 | Rarity     |       253 | Rainbow    |
|    1 |       254 | Princess C |       255 | Princess L |
|    1 |       278 | Martins    |       290 | Karl L     |
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Etsa, I changed the code around a bit, but this functionality worked well for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The comparing of the wins makes no sense for me, furthermore the order by wins, when you do not need it for the result. Quick and dirty solution, but should match your requirement:

```
SELECT a.player_id, a.name, b.player_id + 1, b.name
FROM standings as a 
INNER JOIN standings AS b
     ON abs(a.player_id - b.player_id) <= 1
     AND a.name = b.name
WHERE a.wins = b.wins
ORDER BY a.player_id;
```

Comment: Hi Manuzi, thanks for your answer. Etsa's suited what I needed as an end product better though. Thank you for your help.